# how to initialize a youtube video that is in another class from the main activity without extending

Tags: java, android, android-studio, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to implement a service to a YouTube video so that I can run it in the background, but in the process I had a question ... to use the YouTubePlayerView of the YouTube app it is necessary to inherit from YouTubeBaseActivity and when creating another class I need also inherit from Service .. since multiple inheritance is not allowed, it could not execute in the same class the `variablename.initialize (key, this);` The question would be how to execute this from the service class or even from the Main Activity?

this is the code of the youtube api

```
public class youtube extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements 
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

public String pass="AIzaSyBayBrWcKk9SEQESW7zed_mu1_IXxiy_Z0";
YouTubePlayerView yutu;


@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    yutu=(YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
    yutu.initialize(pass,this);

}


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    if (!b){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("y7d9VLRO3vc");
    }

}
```

How could you initialize this code from the main activity or another class?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to odd this it just might cause some issues along the way.

You can call a function with the initialization from another class by making the function you are calling static.

EXAMPLE:

MainActivity:

```
public static void YouTube(){
    yutu.initialize(pass,this);


}
```

ExampleActivity:

```
MainActivity.YouTube();
```

As you can see, ExampleActivity is calling MainActivity's YouTube function.